# How to download MacTeX 2011 now that MacTex 2012 is available

Tags: texlive, mactex, distributions

Is there a way to download the older MacTeX-2011? I am transitioning to a new mac and would prefer to have both MacTeX2011 and the 2012 version available.  I thought I was in luck when I found the the page: http://www.tug.org/mactex/2011, but sadly the link does not work and neither do the mirrors.

Comment: This is where having TeX Collection DVDs is handy :-)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

TUG maintain an [archive of historic material](ftp://tug.org/historic/), which includes [TeX Live versions](ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/) and [MacTeX images](ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/mactex/). Thus you should be OK to get set up for anything over the past few years.

Comment: Based in the dates, I don't think these included the updated packages for TeXLive2011. Perhaps those are available elsewhere. What I am after is TeXLive2011 with all the latest packages that were available with TeXLive2011.

Comment: @PeterGrill Not available, I think. Most people who want 'archive' versions seem to want 'as on the DVD' and _don't_ update during a year.

Comment: I can see the logic in that as normally one would be able to update from the original DVD release, but in the past when I attempted to update TeXLive2010 once 2011 was available I was not able to. Perhaps just copying `/usr/local/texlive` might be sufficient on a Mac?

Answer (score 6):

You could try downloading using BitTorrent. The [MacTeX 2011 torrent file](http://www.tug.org/mactex/2011/MacTeX.mpkg.zip.torrent) is still online.

Comment: But you won't find many seeders.

Comment: It's not available any more.