# Manually copy older TeXLive2011 from one Mac to a new Mac

Tags: texlive, mactex, distributions

From an earlier question of mine, it was determined that one can **not** obtain the latest version of older releases (ex. TeXLive2010, TeXLive2011).  I am upgrading my Mac and would like to know the process of copying over *manually* the files from a Mac that has TeXLive2010 and TeXLive2011 installed.  I'd prefer to **not** use the Migration assistant, so that I can control exactly what is being updated.

So, what I naively tried was:

- Copy `/usr/local/texlive/2010` and `/usr/local/texlive/2011` form old Mac to new Mac.
- Install TeXLive2012 which created `/usr/local/texlive/2012` on new Mac.

On my older Mac I have the following in my Preferences panel:

[image]

But on my new Mac I only have `TeXLive-2012` shown, and want to know how to get that to show the other two versions.

So, what other files do I need to manually copy over so that I can have access to all three versions? Deleting and reinstalling TeXLive2012 is not a problem.

### Notes:

- This is a followup up to [How to download MacTeX 2011 now that MacTex 2012 is available](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65674/how-to-download-mactex-2011-now-that-mactex-2012-is-available)

Comment: I'm not in my Mac right now, but I believe the explanation relies inside `/Library/TeX`. There must be something there that governs the TeX Distribution Data structure. I found some hints [here](http://www.tug.org/mactex/uninstalling.html). `:)`

Comment: You should try copying also `/Library/TeX/Distributions/TeXLive-2011.texdist/`

Comment: @PauloCereda: There were two directories `~/Library/texlive/2010`, and `~/Library/texlive/2011`. I copied those over (and rebooted), but still only see `TeXLive 2012` in the Preferences.

Comment: @egreg: I also copied over `/Library/TeX/Distributions/TeXLive-2010.texdist` and `/Library/TeX/Distributions/TeXLive-2011.texdist` (and rebooted), but still only see `TeXLive2012` in the Preferences Pane.

Comment: @PeterGrill: Interesting, I think it should work. Maybe `/Library/TeX/Distributions/TeXDist-description.rtf` has some hints on what's happening, but as far as I read the document, the TeX pane in the Preferences should recognize `.texdist`'s automatically.

Comment: @PauloCereda or egreg: You want to post an answer based on these comments. I am pretty sure that my TeXLive2011 is working properly now, and hope that my corrupted TeXLive2012 issues are behind me.

Comment: PauloCereda or @egreg: You want to post an answer based on these comments. I am pretty sure that my TeXLive2011 is working properly now, and hope that my corrupted TeXLive2012 issues are behind me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also copy

```
/Library/TeX/Distributions/TeXLive-2011.texdist/
```

which is what the Preference pane uses to know that the distribution is present.

Also the "home" folders referring to variable parts of the distribution should be copied:

```
~/Library/texlive/2011
```

but this has minor priority, as it contains things that will be rebuilt in case of need.