# Corrupted TeXLive2012 installation? (Option clash for currfile)

Tags: texlive, incompatibility, standalone, currfile

### Background:

As per [Manually copy older TeXLive2011 from one Mac to a new Mac](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67438/manually-copy-older-texlive2011-from-one-mac-to-a-new-mac), I attempted to get TeXLive2010 and TeXLive2011 (with the latest libraries) on a newer mac.  The older releases are not available now that TeXLive2012 is the current release.

Based on the comments there, I copied over various files/directories and thought all was well as I could select between all three versions on my new mac. So I gave up my older mac...

The older releases appeared to work once I replaced the **entire** directory `/Library/TeX/Distributions` with the old version.

### Problem:

But now, with TeXLive2012, and the simple document below I get:

> LaTeX Error: Option clash for package currfile.

### Attempted Fix:

Thinking that my TeXLive2012 got corrupted I reinstalled TeXLive2012 (without deleting the earlier version) and updated all the packages. This yields:

> Cannot open /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg for writing: No such file or directory at /usr/local/texlive/2012/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm line 2818.

More details of this log file are below.

### Question:

- Can someone confirm that the file below compiles fine for you with TeXLive2012.
- What is the minimum directories/files that I should delete before attempting to reinstall TeXLive2012? I would very much like to keep the TeXLive2010 and TeXLive2011 releases and not loose them in the process.  Is there perhaps something simpler I could do to resolve this?

### Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{standalone}% moving this after currfile is loaded does not result in error.
\usepackage[realmainfile]{currfile}% 

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

### TexLive Utility Log

```
2012-08-24 17:40:41 -0700 Warning tlu_ipctask[11509]    tlmgr: package log updated at /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr.log
2012-08-24 17:40:41 -0700 Warning tlu_ipctask[11509]    running mktexlsr ...
2012-08-24 17:40:41 -0700 Notice tlu_ipctask[11509] Installation complete; reconfiguring TeX Live
2012-08-24 17:40:45 -0700 Warning tlu_ipctask[11509]    done running mktexlsr.
2012-08-24 17:40:45 -0700 Warning tlu_ipctask[11509]    running mtxrun --generate ...
2012-08-24 17:40:54 -0700 Warning tlu_ipctask[11509]    done running mtxrun --generate.
2012-08-24 17:40:57 -0700 Warning tlu_ipctask[11509]    Cannot open /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg for writing: No such file or directory at /usr/local/texlive/2012/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm line 2818.
2012-08-24 17:40:59 -0700 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation _runUntilChildExit][11149]    kqueue noted that pid 11510 exited (/usr/texbin/tlmgr --repository http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/systems/texlive/tlnet/ --machine-readable --persistent-downloads update --all)
2012-08-24 17:40:59 -0700 Notice tlu_ipctask[11509] child process pid = 11510 exited
2012-08-24 17:41:00 -0700 Error tlu_ipctask[11509]  Value of errno is Invalid argument
2012-08-24 17:41:00 -0700 Error tlu_ipctask[11509]  *** ERROR *** exit status of pid = 11510 was 2
2012-08-24 17:41:00 -0700 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation _runUntilChildExit][11149]    waitpid returned 11509, WIFEXITED(512) = 1, errno = 0 (No error)
2012-08-24 17:41:00 -0700 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation _runUntilChildExit][11149]    kqueue noted that tlu_ipctask (pid = 11509) exited with status 2
2012-08-24 17:41:10 -0700 Notice -[TLMLogWindowController awakeFromNib][11149]  Loaded log window controller
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use TeX Live2012 (and also have TeX Live2010 and TeX Live2011 installed) and your test document produces the mentioned error.

I don't think there was a problem with your installation: `standalone` internally loads `currfile` without options so when you load `currfile` *after* `standalone` with the option `realmainfile`, there's a (naturally expected) clash.

Use `realmainfile` as a class option:

```
\documentclass[realmainfile]{standalone}

\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{currfile}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yep that seems to fix this problem. But, I still think there is a problem with my installation as I am getting `LaTeX Error: File `l3candidates.sty' not found` -- will ask in chat or a follow up question.

Comment: Another way is to use `\PassOptionsToPackage{realmainfile}{currfile}` before loading the `standalone` package or `currfile`. Then the packages can be loaded in any order.

Comment: @MartinScharrer If `currfile` is required by `standalone`, why must `currfile` be loaded by the user at all, as shown in the answer?

Comment: @kando: in the example above the `\usepackage{currfile}` is not required, as it is already loaded by `standalone`. The whole problem is just a normal package option clash, i.e. when a package is requested twice with different options.

Comment: @PeterGrill, that means another package (l3candidates or something similar) is missing. Dunno about Mac, but on Fedora I can just ask to install it by `dnf -y install 'tex(l3candidates.sty)` to install the requisite package.

Comment: @vonbrand: Thanks. This problem is quite old so no longer reproducable. I think the option class mentioned in the answer was the actual problem at the time.