# Corrupted TeXLive2012 installation? (File `l3candidates.sty' not found)

Tags: texlive, distributions, updating

This is a follow up to my earlier question, [Corrupted TeXLive2012 installation? (Option clash for currfile)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68684/corrupted-texlive2012-installation-option-clash-for-currfile).  Refer to that question for the history.

With an "updated" TeXLive2012, I am now getting:

> LaTeX Error: File `l3candidates.sty' not found.

with this simple example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

The TeXLive Utility says everything is up to date.

### Question:

- Can someone confirm that the file above compiles fine for you with TeXLive2012.
- What is the minimum directories/files that I should delete before attempting to reinstall TeXLive2012? I would very much like to keep the TeXLive2010 and TeXLive2011 releases and not loose them in the process.  Is there perhaps something simpler I could do to resolve this?

Comment: I can compile your MWE without problem. It produces 2 pages with horizontal and vertical white strips.

Comment: @GarbageCollector: Thanks. I am assuming you are using TeXLive2012.  Wait... It shouldn't produce _any_ output?

Comment: I am using TeXLive 2012 that I installed fewer than 2 weeks ago. If I add a dummy text `test` then it produces a tight output with `test` text.

Comment: You can try: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55614/update-install-the-newest-version-of-latex3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It certainly does sound like your installation has gone wrong, as `l3candidates` should be part of [`l3kernel`](http://ctan.org/pkg/l3kernel), and for me on a freshly-updated TL2012 I do get the file correctly located

```
palladium:~ joseph$ kpsewhich l3candidates.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3candidates.sty
```

Rather than go for the drastic approach of reinstalling all of TeX Live, I would just redo this one package. As you mention the TeX Live Utility, I assume you are using a Mac. In that, from the Packages list you can use the Filter box to find `l3kernel`, select it then choose 'Reinstall Selected Packages' from the Actions menu (Or <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>). Alternatively, at the Terminal you could give in instruction

```
sudo tlmgr install --reinstall l3kernel
```

which will also work for Linux and Windows users. (Windows users may need to run the Command Prompt as Administrator, and will certainly not need `sudo`.) For completeness, Windows users with the same issue can use the TeX Live Manager, user the Match box to find `l3kernel`. The TeX Live Manageer does not have the 'reinstall' concept available, so you will need to remove `l3kernel` here then separately reinstall it.

Of course, the 'repair' instructions here are entirely general: if you have what seems to be a corrupted package then you can use the appropriate interface to `tlmgr` to reinstall (or remove-then-install), rather than have to reinstall all of TeX Live!

Comment: Thanks Joseph, this seems to work. I had looked for `l3candidates.sty` and did not see it int he list of pacakges in the TeXLive Utility, and did not know to look for `l3kernal`. However, don't understand why this was missing, and a reinstall did not fix this issue.

Comment: @PeterGrill It's not a package, it's just a file, so it does not show up in the manager. You'd see exactly the same with any single missing file from a package made up of lots.