# Where Can I download older version of TeXLive?

Tags: texlive, repositories

I need to download TeXlive 2011 for some special reason. But I can't find it in [tug.org](http://tug.org) website there is only latest version of TexLive. 
Any help will be appreciated. 
thanks.

Edit: the Question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65674/how-to-download-mactex-2011-now-that-mactex-2012-is-available) is about macTex not Texlive. Even Though the answer is general answer that works for this question.

Comment: I should add that the site seems to be refusing connections, but I don't know if it's just temporary.

Comment: I'm curious how duplicate-marking works in this case. The question is not a duplicate in my opinion because the other question is MacTeX-specific. However, the answer there is a general answer that applies to this question. We treat this case as a "duplicate question" ?

Comment: @egreg Thanks! Even though that question is different, But I got my answer there. thanks :)

Comment: @scottkosty Thanks. Totally Agree with you ;)